# Unit test a V-If with Jest

Tags: html, unit-testing, vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs

How do I test the following v-if on my parent component using Jest?

Parent:

```
    <div class="systemIsUp" v-if="systemStatus == true">
      foo
    </div>
    <div class="systemIsDown" v-else>
     bar
    </div>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'File Name',
  data () {
    return {
      systemStatus: null,
    }
  },

</script>
```

Here is my current setup for testing if those divs render when I change the value of the systemStatus variable
Unit Test:

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import FileName from 'path'

describe('FileName', () => {
  //Declare wrapper for this scope 
  const wrapper = shallowMount(FileName)
  it('Should display message saying that the system is down if "systemStatus" data variable is false', () => {
    expect(wrapper.html().includes('.systemIsDown')).toBe(false)
    wrapper.setData({ systemStatus: false})
    expect(wrapper.html().includes('.systemIsDown')).toBe(true)
  });
});
```

I have tried using *contains* and *toContain* instead of *includes* but still cannot get it to work, Jest returns the following:

```
    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: true
    Received: false

           expect(wrapper.html().includes('.systemIsDown')).toBe(false)
           wrapper.setData({ systemStatus: false })
           expect(wrapper.html().includes('.systemIsDown')).toBe(true)
                                                            ^
```

Clearly it cannot see the systemIsDown div at all and does not think it exists hence why the first expect passes but how can I get it to see the div when the systemStatus variable is updated?
Thanks

Comment: `.html().includes(text)` isn't going to treat `text` as a *selector*, it's just searching in a string. Look at what `wrapper.html()` actually gives you.

Comment: I know that wrapper.html() will return a string version of the HTML input, however I still cannot pull out if the div when using wrapper.html()).toContain('.systemIsDown') as I get the following:
Expected substring: ".systemIsDown"
    Received string:    "<div>
      <div class=\"systemIsDown\">
        <div class=\"row main\">
          <div class=\"col-sm-12 col-md-12 whiteBackground\">" ie the full thing under the v-else

Comment: And `'<div class="systemIsDown">bar</div>'.includes('.systemIsDown')` is false because, again, *it's not a CSS selector*. It's just looking for the literal substring. If you want to use HTML-based assertions, don't flatten it to a string.

Comment: Okay, I changed the assertion so that it is now: 
`let division = wrapper.html()`
`expect(division.includes("systemIsDown")).toBe(true)`

which finds the div fine, but when I check the opposite version (systemIsUp) my `wrapper.setData({ systemStatus: true })` is not changing the data variable, is there data leakage between assertions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changed around the assertion to look for specific CSS selector as follows:

```
wrapper.setData({ systemStatus: false})
expect(wrapper.find(".systemIsDown")).toBeTruthy()
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work, if you want to check given DOM element has been created (or not):

```js
expect(wrapper.find(".systemIsDown").exists()).toBe(true) // or false
```

more [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/unit-testing-vue-components.html)